# How to manage number of cores used on my institution's server

Tags: r, multi-core, htop

I'm using a remote server where I'm not supposed to request more than 24 of the 100 cores.

I'm running a couple of R scripts which seem to be using too many...

How can I tell, in htop, how many cores an individual user (myself) is using? I can see the 'load average', which is for all users, and I can add up the MEM% for my processes.

Is there some R command I could use to limit the number of cores? The script I'm using doesn't even parallelize any process explicitly but perhaps the R package is grabbing cores for me.

Comment: Did you look at schedtool, it can set affinity of a process for cores.

Answer (score 0):

print info about cpu:

```
lscpu
```

change use cpu:

```
chcpu -d 25-99
chcpu -g 25-99
```

`core 25 -99` go to offline on the remote server

if you want to limit kernels for a process then use cgroup

Answer (score 0):

u will have to **isolcpus** by editting the grub file
**this will reserve cores for system only**

firstly check number of cpus present

```
lscpu
```

check firmware

```
ls -larth /sys/firmware
```

edit grub

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub
```

then add isolcpus parameter

```
# mostly keep starting numa cores for system
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" isolcpus={how much u want to allocat for use by scripts}
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

if efi exists then
then compile with

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg

           else
            
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg
```

**warning!** if no errors during compilation only then reboot
reboot the machine

```
reboot now
```

lastly check if the changes have persisted
after re-login

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```